# Importing the multiarray numpy extension module failed (Just with Anaconda)

Tags: python, numpy, anaconda

I'm quite new to Python/Anaconda, and I'm facing an issue that I couldn't solve on my own or googling.
When I'm running Python on cmd I can import and use numpy. Working fine.

When I'm running scripts on Spyder, or just trying to import numpy on Anaconda Prompt this error message appears:

> ImportError: Importing the multiarray numpy extension module failed.
>   Most likely you are trying to import a failed build of numpy. If
>   you're working with a numpy git repo, try git clean -xdf (removes all
>   files not under version control). Otherwise reinstall numpy.
>
> Original error was: cannot import name 'multiarray'

I don't know if there are relations to it, but I cannot update conda, as well. When I try to update I receive Permission Errors.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

The following solved this issue for me:

```
pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall numpy
```

Answer (score 0):

I feel like I would have to know a little more but, it seems to be that you need to reinstall numpy and check if the complete install was successful. Keep in mind that Anaconda is a closed environment so you don't have as much control.

with regards to the permissions issue you may have installed it with a superuser/admin. That would mean that in order to update you would have to update with your superuser/admin.

Comment: about numpy installation: 
before installing Anaconda I had Python36 installed and had already installed a series of packages using pip. 

i managed to update Anaconda and numpy running the prompt in administrator mode, but the error mentioned persists

Comment: `pip uninstall numpy`  
`pip install numpy`  
solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly perform invalidate cache and restart if you are using PyCharm.

No need to uninstall numpy or run any command.